# How can I avoid one word on the last line with CSS?

Tags: css

Suppose a text shows up as follows on an HTML page (just one word too long to fit on one line):

```
Lorem ipsum dolores amet foo
bar
```

How can one avoid with CSS that the last word appears on the last line, and force two (or more)?

```
Lorem ipsum dolores amet
foo bar
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent having just one hanging word on a new line in an HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974448/how-can-i-prevent-having-just-one-hanging-word-on-a-new-line-in-an-html-element)

Answer (score 27):

I don't think you can do this in pure CSS.

You would have to either put a non-breaking space in between the last two words:

```
foo&nbsp;bar
```

or put the last two words into a `span`:

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap">foo bar</span>
```

Comment: +1.  This sort of thing can be automated pretty easily with a little javascript, too.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it can be done in CSS alone but this is what I came up with to solve the one word per line problem. It will replace the last n spaces with a non breaking space for all the matched elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/jackvial/19e3pm6e/2/

```
    function noMoreLonelyWords(selector, numWords){

      // Get array of all the selected elements
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      var i;
      for(i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i){

        // Split the text content of each element into an array
        var textArray = elems[i].innerText.split(" ");

        // Remove the last n words and join them with a none breaking space
        var lastWords = textArray.splice(-numWords, numWords).join("&nbsp;");

        // Join it all back together and replace the existing
        // text with the new text
        var textMinusLastWords = textArray.join(" ");
        elems[i].innerHTML = textMinusLastWords + " " +  lastWords;
      }
    }

    // Goodbye lonely words
    noMoreLonelyWords("p", 3);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just wrote this dependency-free JS snippet that will solve this very problem

https://github.com/ajkochanowicz/BuddySystem

Essentially this is the source code

```
var buddySystem=function(e){var n=[],r=[]
n=e.length?e:n.concat(e),Array.prototype.map.call(n,function(e){var n=String(e.innerHTML)
n=n.replace(/\s+/g," ").replace(/^\s|\s$/g,""),r.push(n?e.innerHTML=n.replace(new RegExp("((?:[^ ]* ){"+((n.match(/\s/g)||0).length-1)+"}[^ ]*) "),"$1&nbsp;"):void 0)})}
```

and you can implement it by doing this

```
objs = document.getElementsByClassName('corrected');
buddySystem(objs);
```

Now you'll never have a word by itself for any tags with the `corrected` class.

You can also use jQuery if you want.

`$(".corrected").buddySystem()`

Check out the link for all possibilities.

Comment: How can I get this solution to not only replace the last space but all spaces between the 2 or more last words?

Comment: @TheStoryCoder Checkout my solution above. I've added a link to a JS Fiddle for it.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done with CSS, but Shaun Inman wrote a very useful bit of Javascript to help with this a while ago:

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2006/08/22/widont_wordpress_plugin

It's a Wordpress plugin, but there are plenty of non-Wordpress clones around.

Comment: This post by Shaun is from 2006, a little old in my opinion to rely on.

Comment: Age doesn't matter — it's a very simple Javascript pattern which worked when it was devised, and continues to work to this day.

Comment: Don't understand why this answer has been voted down. Despite being a few year's old, Shaun's code is still very relevant. Seems a little ridiculous to disregard the validity of a something just because of it's age.

Answer (score 1):

If JavaScript is an option, one can use [typogr.js](https://github.com/ekalinin/typogr.js), a JavaScript "typogrify" implementation. This particular filter is called Widont.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typogr/0.6.7/typogr.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.body.innerHTML = typogr.widont(document.body.innerHTML);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I wonder if it has any relation to the WordPress plugin of the same name. (Both are poorly named - these things *aren't* widows at all.)

Comment: Looks like typogrify cites Shaun Inman's implementation as the original, so... I guess I know who to point the finger at.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76701845/2076595. Nowadays, after many years of waiting, you can do this with CSS: `text-wrap: pretty`.

I initially added that answer to this question here as well, but a moderator deleted my answer saying I should flag questions as duplicates instead. All good, but unfortunately I don’t have enough points to cast duplicate-votes so here we are: me referring to the other answer. Sorry about that, but apparently that’s the rules.

For completeness: this questions is the OG question. These two other questions are duplicates and should get marked as duplicates of this question:

- [How can I prevent having just one hanging word on a new line in an HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31974448/2076595)
- [Prevent line break between last word of an element and another element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38296454/2076595)

Answer (score 0):

here's some newbie php that you might use if you wanted to do this in wordpress

```
function add_nobr_spans($string) {
  $words = explode(' ', $string);
  if (count($words) < 3){
    return $string;
  }
  $last_word = array_pop($words);
  while ($last_word == "") {
    $last_word = array_pop($words);
  }
  if (preg_match('#[<>]+#is', $last_word)) {
    return $string;
  }
  $almost_last_word = array_pop($words);
  if (preg_match('#[<>]+#is', $almost_last_word)) {
    return $string;
  }
  array_push($words, "<span class='nobr'>".$almost_last_word." ".$last_word."</span>");
  return implode(' ', $words);
}
function no_widows_for_end_tag($input, $end_tag){
  $split_stuff = explode($end_tag, $input);
  $split_stuff = array_map('add_nobr_spans', $split_stuff);
  $result = implode($end_tag, $split_stuff);
  return $result;
}
function no_widows($string) {
  $string = no_widows_for_end_tag($string, "</p>");
  $string = no_widows_for_end_tag($string, "</h3>");
  $string = no_widows_for_end_tag($string, "</h4>");
  $string = no_widows_for_end_tag($string, "</h5>");
  return $string;
}
```