# How can I prevent having just one hanging word on a new line in an HTML element?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm building a simple webpage with some marketing content. One thing I don't like is that if a line of text is too long, it will wrap onto the next line, which is *fine*, but it often wraps in such a way that there is only one word on the new line, which is just bad news from a design standpoint.

*Such and such doesn't have to be difficult. Such and such product makes it

easy*

What can I do to dynamically ensure at least two words on each hanging line?

*Such and such doesn't have to be difficult. Such and such product makes 
it
easy*

Comment: *"which is just bad news from a design standpoint."*...I dispute your contention. If a line wraps to just a single word so be it...a least it looks natural rather than forcing an unnatural break.

Comment: @Paulie_D - fwiw, it's common in the realm of print media to obsess on this stuff..  page layout applications (well, back when I used them it was Quark XPress and Aldus/Adobe PageMaker) like InDesign have built in features to aid in the prevention of "widows" / "orphans" ..

Comment: Yeah...but this isnt print...it's the web. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/widows

Comment: I agree, having a hanging word is undesirable. "It's the web" is not a great excuse IMO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I avoid one word on the last line with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823722/how-can-i-avoid-one-word-on-the-last-line-with-css)

Comment: It looks like [CSS Fragmentation Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-break-3/) might have a proper fix for this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The simple solution is to use a non-breaking space between the last two words at the end of a paragraph.

```
&nbsp;
```

---

```
<p>Such and such doesn't have to be difficult. Such and such product makes it&nbsp;easy</p>
```

This could get tedious if you have a lot of content and especially if it is business controlled. In that case you may be able to find a library or write a solution that automatically inserts the non-breaking space between the last two words of every paragraph for you.

Try this:
https://matthewlein.com/tools/widowfix

Comment: similarly, you could wrap the last two words in a `<nobr>` tag, e.g.

Comment: @Jon z - `<nobr>` is obsolete - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT:** The [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31974553/992504) is much cleaner -- you should probably use that instead. I'm leaving my answer up because it does work and it has some value for weird cases (e.g. if you're using a dash instead of a space, if you don't want to use `&nbsp;`, etc).

---

Here's a neat little solution. Create a CSS class like this:

```
.nobr { white-space:nowrap; }
```

Any element with the class "nobr" will not be allowed to wrap white-space (spaces, tabs, etc) onto new lines. So just surround the last two words of your text with a `span.nobr`.

```
<p>Such and such doesn't have to be difficult. Such and such product makes <span class="nobr">it easy</span></p>
```

Comment: or he could just put in a  <br> tag

Comment: A `<br>` tag would _force_ the paragraph to break before the last two words, which isn't what he wants. Doing that, you might end up with a line with one word above the line with the last two words, and that'd be worse.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a `<nobr>last two words.</nobr>` tag.

This also gives the benefit of not cutting off any HTML flourishes you may be doing, eg:

```
<b>&ldquo;</b>Here's a big statement I don't want <nobr>cutting off<b>&rdquo;</b>.</nobr>
```

Comment: <nobr></nobr> remains supported by every browser, but as a precaution include the following in your style sheet:
nobr {
  white-space:nowrap;
}

Answer (score 5):

In CSS, you can use [`text-wrap: pretty`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-4/#valdef-text-wrap-pretty) for this.

```css
p {
  text-wrap: pretty;
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/oNQqMXv

Note that `text-wrap: pretty` is only supported in Chrome 117 *(current Canary)* at the time of posting, with other browsers hopefully following soon.

Also see https://www.youtube.com/clip/UgkxMs0HXf1mwkTZQRrSwtWPxrmVsSHFmN8X, showing how it behaves and how it compares to [`text-wrap: balance`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/css-text-wrap-balance/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&nbsp;` HTML entity or one of the [non-breaking-space ASCII character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Here is one :